# Angular 5 @input() object property binding error

Tags: angular

I'm not sure if the errors I'm getting:

```
***ERROR**: Can't bind to 'obj.Name' since it isn't a known property of 'comp'.*
```

is a result of Angular not allowing this behavior. The intent is simply to bind to @input object properties.
Code:

```
// comp.component.ts
...
@Input() obj: ObjType = {
Name: ''
}

// comp2.html
...
// this HTML is passing the value from comp2.html to comp component
<app-comp [obj.Name]="MyNameIs"></app-comp>
```

I would expect the "MyNameIs" value to get passed back into the obj.Name property, but I'm getting the above error. Is this something I'm not doing correctly, or simply not something Angular (v5) does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Input` is reserved for parent component to child component property binding.

For example: 
**parent.component.ts** should contain a property:

`public myNameIs = { name: 'Marie Curie'};`

***parent.component.html*** Inside the parent template include the child component and bind to the properties:

`<child-comp [obj]="MyNameIs"></child-comp>`

**child.component.ts** Inside the child component use the `@Input` decorator to bind to the property.

`@Input() obj: ObjType = {}`

**child.component.html** Then you may use the property in your child component or template.

`<h3> {{obj?.name}}</h3>`

Here is a [StackBlitz demo for your use case](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-app-init-4jgosm)

**In your case you can't bind to `obj.Name`, because the `Input()` decorator is bound to the object `obj` not the specific property  `obj.Name`.** All you have to do to fix your error is pass the value in like:
`<child-comp [obj]="MyNameIs"></child-comp>` (See the working StackBlitz I made.)

Comment: I updated the post to reflect a mistake I had made: the html is passing the values to a separate component, hence the need for the @Input()